# Auto load Office Centralized deployed custom Add-in using upload XML manifest file

Tags: web, office365, add-in, autoload, openxml-sdk

I have created a customized add-in to PowerPoint and I deployed that through Centralized Deployment using upload manifest file in the Office 365 admin center.

I want this add-in to be loaded automatically when the user opens a document, for this I was used Open XML SDK to configure Office documents to automatically open a specified add-in
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin

But currently, I am not able to load it automatically. I am getting an error   "Add-in Warning This add-in is no longer available."

.

I have mentioned two lines of code used in the program , here we used two ids for webextension and WebExtensionStoreReference.

please advice on these two lines to what parameter and values  I want to use correctly

```
 We.WebExtension webExtension1 = new We.WebExtension(){ Id = "{52811C31-4593-43B8-A697-EB873422D156}" };
 We.WebExtensionStoreReference webExtensionStoreReference1 = new We.WebExtensionStoreReference() { Id = "af8fa5ba-4010-4bcc-9e03-a91ddadf6dd3", Version = "1.0.0.0", Store = "EXCatalog", StoreType = "EXCatalog" };
```

please help if anyone knows about this....!!